# Inverting button action on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, button

I'm working with WordPress site where I want to show elements on button click.

I found this script, but it works the opposite how I want - it hides, instead of shows content. How can I invert it?

**I want it to be hidden when pages loads and appear when clicked on button**

Preview: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GGXM3P219FCN

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var togBtn = $('.tog');
  var allergerns = $('.allergerns');

  togBtn.one('click', hideAllergerns);

  function hideAllergerns() {
    allergerns.fadeOut();
    togBtn.one('click', showAllergerns);
  }

  function showAllergerns() {
    allergerns.fadeIn();
    togBtn.one('click', hideAllergerns);
  }
});
```

```css
.allergerns {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #4aa3df
}

.tog {
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
 <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="tog">toggle</button>
<div  class="allergerns"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Java is totally another programming language.

Comment: _"How it i invert it?"_ - Click the button again? o.O

Comment: I want it to be hidden on page load

Comment: You can add
```
.allergerns {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #4aa3df
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the **initial CSS styles**.
Use JavaScript to **toggle a specific class** that shows your elements:

- References should be stored inside a `data-*` Attribute, not by copy pasting code in case you need multiple toggling buttons or *pane* elements
- Animations should be done using CSS, not jQuery. Preferably use GPU accelerable CSS properties like `opacity`, `transform` etc.
- Finally, use jQuery's `.toggleClass()` to trigger a desired style-state

```js
jQuery(function ($) { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  $("[data-toggle]").on("click", function() {
    $(this.dataset.toggle).toggleClass("is-active");
  });
  
});
```

```css
.pane {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #4aa3df;

  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  transition: 0.3s;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.pane.is-active {
  max-height: initial;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button class="tog" data-toggle="#pane-1">Toggle 1</button>
<div id="pane-1" class="pane">Pane 1</div>

<button class="tog" data-toggle="#pane-2">Toggle 2</button>
<div id="pane-2" class="pane">Pane 2</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```